# Bind Win+D to minimize all opened windows in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

Is is possible to bind <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all opened windows (yeah, it's my habit)? Now I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Ubuntu.

I've tried `System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`, but Win key seems not working there..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `System --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts` you can change the shortcut for "Hide all normal windows and set focus to desktop" from Ctrl-Alt-D to Win-D.

If you have one or both Windows-keys already assigned as compose/meta/whatever-they-call-it-now you have to change it first under `System --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> Options`

Comment: `System` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Layouts` > `Layout options btn` > `Alt/Win key bahavior` > `Add the standart behaviour to Menu key`